# simple_fields_for was remove once the validation occur

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I need some help.

`"= form.association :lead"` : the user can select a lead through select2 via ajax.

`.lead-form-inputs` : the user can create a lead and automatically set the lead_id of the property once it was submitted.

I do have a select2 gem installed and runs the`"= form.association :lead"` as a select2.
As you can see there was a :new_lead input as a boolean(a Checkbox).
Once the checkbox is checked the `"= form.association :lead"` will disappear and the `.lead-form-inputs` class will appear.

PROBLEM:

1. Once i submitted the form(on purpose) just to trigger the validation. The `= form.simple_fields_for :lead do | lead_builder |` entire inputs is removed.

> I need that `form.simple_fields_for` to stay because if the user want to create another lead yet the validations has been triggered the `form.simple_fields_for` is not present. Yet still the user can go to the property/new just to refresh the entire page.

2. If i select a lead using the `"= form.association :lead"` and submitted the form(on purpose) just to trigger the validation. The `form.simple_fields_for` stays but `"= form.association :lead"` is empty.
   I said earlier that "i select a lead". Once i checked the checkbox. The `form.simple_fields_for` inputs was filled in. The information filled in to the inputs is that the lead i selected earlier after i submitted the form.

> What i want is that the select2 will still display the lead what i selected.

VIEW:

```
= simple_form_for([:admin, @property], wrapper: :vertical_form, html: { autocomplete: "off", class: "primary-form" }) do |form|
  = form.input :listing_title
  = form.association :lead, collection: [], input_html: { multiple: false }, label: false

  = form.simple_fields_for :lead do | lead_builder |
    = lead_builder.input :new_lead, as: :boolean
    .lead-form-inputs.hide
     = lead_builder.input :status, collection: [['New Lead', 'New Lead'], ['SLC', 'SLC'], ['BLC', 'BLC'], ['Seller Lead', 'Seller Lead'], ['Buyer Lead', 'Buyer Lead'], ['Client', 'Client'], ['Shelf', 'Shelf'], ['Drop', 'Drop']], prompt: "Select Status"
     = lead_builder.input :last_name
     = lead_builder.input :first_name
     = lead_builder.input :middle_initial
     = lead_builder.input :contact_number
     = lead_builder.input :email_address
     = lead_builder.input :company_name
     = lead_builder.input :date_inquired do
     = lead_builder.text_field :date_inquired, class: "datepickerJs", value: @property.lead.date_inquired.blank? ? '' : @property.lead.date_inquired.strftime("%b-%d-%Y")
     = lead_builder.input :source, collection: [['Website', 'Website'], ['Facebook', 'Facebook'], ['Facebook Ads', 'Facebook Ads'], ['DotProperty', 'DotProperty'], ['Referral', 'Referral'], ['Network', 'Network'], ['Old Leads', 'Old Leads']], prompt: "Select Source"
  = form.submit "Save", class: "button action-button__save-button primary-form__submit-btn"

:javascript
  $( "#property_lead_id" ).select2({
    closeOnSelect: true,
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: "Select lead",
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    ajax: {
      url: '/admin/leads.json',
      data: function (params) {
        var query = {
          search: params.term,
        }
        return query;
      },
      processResults: function (data) {
        return {
          results: $.map(data.leads, function(obj, key) {
            responsejson = {
                id: obj.id,
                text: `${obj.first_name} ${obj.middle_initial} ${obj.last_name}`,
            };
            return responsejson;
          })
        };

      }
    }
  });
```

Property CONTROLLER:

```
def new
 @property = Property.new
 @lead = @property.build_lead
end

def create
 @property = Property.new(property_params)
 respond_to do |format|
  if @property.save
   format.html { redirect_to edit_admin_property_path(@property), notice: 'Property was successfully created.' }
  else
   format.html { render :new }
  end
 end
end

def property_params
  params.require(:property).permit(:listing_title, :lead_id, lead_attributes: [:id, :status, :last_name, :first_name, :middle_initial, :contact_number, :email_address, :company_name, :date_inquired, :source, :new_lead])
end
```

MODELS:

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :lead
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :lead, reject_if: :reject_lead

 def reject_lead(attributes)
    attributes["new_lead"] != '1'
  end
end

class Lead < ApplicationRecord
 attr_accessor :new_lead

 has_many :properties
 
 validates :status,
            :last_name,
            :first_name,
            :middle_initial,
            :contact_number,
            :email_address,
            :company_name,
            :date_inquired,
            :source,
            presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PROBLEM ANSWER:

1. I define a new method in the property model and use a callback after_validation.

```
 after_validation :leader_builder

 def leader_builder
   self.build_lead unless lead
 end
```

2. I added a value to the collection attribute on my select2.

```
= form.association :lead, collection: Lead.order("id ASC").map{|r| [r.full_name, r.id]}, input_html: { multiple: false }, label: false
```